# Query to get SER_NUMBER having Events in a Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need help  writing a SQL query to find out the `SER_NUMBER` which is having `EVENT_ID` in the following order 101, 102, 103, 135 and also get the time difference between 103 and 135.

This is my sample data:

| SER_NUMBER | EVENT_LOG_ID | EVENT_ID | EVENT_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12344 | 4432 | 135 | 2022-08-03 01.46.37.0000000 |
| 12344 | 4433 | 136 | 2022-08-03 01.46.41.0000000 |
| 12344 | 4433 | 101 | 2022-08-03 01.46.43.0000000 |
| 12344 | 4434 | 102 | 2022-08-03 01.46.43.0000000 |
| 12344 | 4435 | 103 | 2022-08-03 01.46.43.0000000 |
| 12344 | 4436 | 135 | 2022-08-03 08.54.03.0000000 |
| 12344 | 4437 | 136 | 2022-08-03 18.54.03.0000000 |
| 12344 | 4438 | 104 | 2022-08-03 18.53.39.0000000 |
| 12344 | 4439 | 105 | 2022-08-03 18.53.42.0000000 |

As shown in this table, there will be multiple number of `SER_NUMBER` in the table and expected result

| SER_NUMBER | TIME_DIFF |
| --- | --- |
| 12344 | 07 hrs |

Comment: You have two columns named EVENT_ID in your sample data. It seems like the first column with that name is not relevant to the question?

Comment: It's not possible for a table to have two columns named identically.

Comment: corrected column name , sorry for confusion

Comment: How does the 104 row factor in?

Answer (score 0):

You left out some information so I made a couple assumptions. [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ziJBVG6a)

*As already mentioned in the comments, you can't have two columns named EVENT_ID so I renamed one.

```
CREATE TABLE events (SER_NUMBER INT, UNNECESSARY_ID INT, EVENT_ID INT, EVENT_Date DATETIME2);
INSERT INTO events VALUES
(12344, 4432,   135,    N'2022-08-03 01:46:37.0000000'),
(12344, 4433,   136,    N'2022-08-03 01:46:41.0000000'),
(12344, 4433,   101,    N'2022-08-03 01:46:43.0000000'),
(12344, 4434,   102,    N'2022-08-03 01:46:43.0000000'),
(12344, 4435,   103,    N'2022-08-03 01:46:43.0000000'),
(12344, 4436,   135,    N'2022-08-03 08:54:03.0000000'),
(12344, 4437,   136,    N'2022-08-03 18:54:03.0000000'),
(12344, 4438,   104,    N'2022-08-03 18:53:39.0000000'),
(12344, 4439,   105,    N'2022-08-03 18:53:42.0000000');
```

You didn't say what to do if there is more than one datetime for 103 or 135. I assumed earliest 103 and latest 135.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
         E1.SER_NUMBER
       , DATEDIFF(HOUR, MIN(E1.EVENT_DATE), MAX(E2.EVENT_DATE)) hours_diff
    FROM events E1
    JOIN events E2 ON E1.SER_NUMBER = E2.SER_NUMBER
                  AND E2.EVENT_ID = 135
   WHERE E1.EVENT_ID = 103
GROUP BY E1.SER_NUMBER
```

You also didn't mention how precise you need the result. Your example showed hours so I went with that.

| SER_NUMBER | hours_diff |
| --- | --- |
| 12344 | 7 |

Comment: Thank you for  answer ,  i need to identify the SER_NUMBER  which is having only EVENT_ID in the following sequence 101, 102, 103, 135  , in the answer  only  103 and 135 are taken (there is a chance in the data where we have 103 and 135 only ), so we need to consider all 4 events . hours presision is fine and there will be only one date time for 103,135

Comment: I get what you're asking now but there's a problem. SQL Server doesn't store data in order. How do we know what order the EVENT_ID is supposed to be in? Based on you example, it appears it could be the EVENT_LOG_ID but I'm assuming again.